# Eclipse out of memory error, asking to exit workbench

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am using Java EE Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1) Build id: 20150109-0600 and Tomcat 8.0.21. Every time I try to start tomcat, I am getting an out of memory error for which I am attaching a screenshot below:
[image: error screen shot]

I have tried to increase the memory values from the eclipse.ini file, but it dint help. Is there any other workaround for this.....

Comment: Do you have a x86 or x64 installation of eclipse and what about jdk? And how much RAM do your computer have.

Comment: For that matter, what are the original values and what did you increase them to? Have you tried updating to Luna SR2 or Mars and seeing if it's any different?

Comment: check your conf in the eclipse.ini file

Comment: for me it looks related to Tomcat. 
Please check if there is any application start up in tomcat listener which might be causing out of memory. You may like to check tomcat configuration.

Comment: I have x64 installation and jdk 1.8 and 4GB RAM

Comment: -Xms512m
-Xmx1024m are new values, from  -Xms40m
-Xmx256m